# Angular routing issue production after migrating from Angular 12 to Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an issue with Angular routing in a situation where there is an extra segment behind the domain within th eurl (https://domain/my-app/web/)

For localhost I use the following baseHref in the Angular.json
"baseHref": "/test-bui/",
This is meant to be used by everything but the routing (static files, relative location of main.js, vendor.js...)
In Angular I define following for the routing:
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
Localhost routing works fine.

For production I use the following baseHref in the Angular.json.
This is meant to be used by everything but the routing (static files, relative location of main.js, vendor.js...)
"baseHref": "/my-app/web/test-bui/"
In Angular I define following for the routing:
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my-app/web/' }

In Angular I also use a parent route 'test-bui'.

In Angular 14 I have a situation where the routing in production modus doesn't work anymore. I migrated from Angular 12.
My default route doesn't seem to work and the router outlet stays blank.
When I click on a menu with router links I get the following kind of errors:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test-bui/ui/hierarchical-list'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test-bui/ui/hierarchical-list'

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You could try to search for breaking changes between in Angular 12 and Angular 14. I tried to find relevant changes. One might be useful. The type of Route.pathMatch is now more strict. Places that use pathMatch will likely need to be updated to have an explicit Route/Routes type so that TypeScript does not infer the type as string. https://angular.io/guide/update-to-latest-version

Answer (score 0):

You could try to search for breaking changes in Angular 13 and Angular 14.

I tried to find relevant changes here, https://angular.io/guide/update-to-latest-version, and found one that might be useful.

> The type of Route.pathMatch is now more strict. Places that use pathMatch will likely need to be updated to have an explicit Route/Routes type so that TypeScript does not infer the type as string.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was due to the fact that we used a minified Rxjs 7 umd bundle. So we decided to bundle the rxjs javascript ourselves with webpack.

Note that this is in a scenario where CDN files are used for the third party libraries.